# Powershell script waiting for user input and wont exit

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a script silently, its runs fine but then after its run it displays
Succeeded : 0
Press 'Enter' to continue

How can i check if succeeded and then send the enter key..

Note I am running this via the start process command as below but as it is waiting for the user to press enter it never exits:

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\windows\temp\abc.exe" -ArgumentList '/S','/v','/qn' -passthru
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to **check if your executable supports a command-line parameter (option) that skips the prompt at the end**.

If there is none, you can try the following approach, but note that, **as with all attempts to control an application via *simulated user interaction*, the solution is awkward and brittle**:

```sh
# Comment this out to hide the verbose messages.
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

# Load helper assemblies.
Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic, System.Windows.Forms

# Launch the external program.
# In this simple example, cmd.exe is invoked with its internal pause
# command, which waits for a keystroke to continue.
Write-Verbose 'Launching the external program asynchronously...'
# IMPORTANT: Do NOT use -Wait, as that will block execution
#            indefinitely, and prevent you from sending the Enter keystroke.
$process = Start-Process -PassThru cmd '/c pause'

Write-Verbose 'Sleeping for as long as execution is expected to last at a minimum...'
Start-Sleep 5  # Adjust this as needed.

Write-Verbose 'Sending ENTER keystrokes until the window closes...'
while (-not $process.HasExited) {
  # To be safe, activate the external program's window. If that fails, it must be closed already.
  try { [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($process.Id) } catch { break }
  # Send the keystroke.
  [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{Enter}')
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200  # Sleep a little between attempts.
}

Write-Verbose 'The external program''s window is now closed.'
```